# Config Map package name prefixed with namespace + colon

Tags: node.js, angular, requirejs, systemjs

I see an example in Angular2 startup project's System.Config.JS, it likes below:

```
(function (global) {
System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        'app': 'app',
        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
```

My question is: map seems using config path's alias like 'npm', and suffixed it with colon ":", then prepend this string to the package file name, like npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js in the example.

However I looked up over the SystemJS's [config API](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#map) and RequireJS's [config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config), but I did not find any documentation for this usage. Has anyone ever worked on this and can provide some useful link or documentation for that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant part of the documentation is this: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#paths

The doc says:

> Paths allow creating mappings that apply after `map` configuration

This is what Angular2 config does. The colon ":" has no special meaning, it's just to make it more obvious that all the modules come from `npm`.

For example when you import module `@angular/core`:

1. The `@angular/core` is mapped to `npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js` thanks to the `map` option.
2. `npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js` is mapped to `node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js` where the `npm:` is replaced with `node_modules/` thanks to the `paths` option.

You could use any other string than `npm:` it I'd work the same way.

Comment: Oh, right, I missed the "npm:" whole part is a config paths hashtable key not just only "npm". Thank  you for point it to me.